# Twilio Runtime Client SDK

Tags: twilio, runtime, assets

I'm trying to use this piece of code to retrieve a project's assets :

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    let path = Runtime.getAssets()['asset-path'].path;

    console.log('The path is: ' + path);

    callback();

}
```

My question is, which Twilio helper library to I import in order to use Runtime?

Thanks in advance,

Angus

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:

Functions & Assets (API-only)
https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api

Assets
* Read Assets (Example)
https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/api/asset